# How to fix Magento 2 MSI inventory reservation inconsistencies directly via DB?

Tags: magento2, database, inventory, msi, reservations

I see orders that are **closed, canceled or completed** that were created in the reservation table but never removed and they won't be removed since it's triggered when the order changes the status.

I check the reservation running this command below.

```
select * from inventory_reservation where sku='822189036724';
```

[image: Magento 2 MSI inventory reservation compensation fix]

I don't have the lasted version of MSI which includes a command to fix it, so how could I fix it in the DB directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Magento 2.3 or newer**

This CLI below was implemented to solve this issue.

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento inventory:reservation:list-inconsistencies -r -c | xargs -L1 php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento inventory:reservation:create-compensations
```

**Magento 2.2 or older**

This query will return the **reservation IDs** from the reservations from every order that is either **closed**, **complete** or **canceled**, was created more than 2 weeks ago but has its reservation still different than 0 (which affects the salable quantity on the store, once their reservations were not correctly finished).

```
SELECT to_be_deleted.reservation_id FROM (
    SELECT ir3.*, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ir3.metadata, '_id":"', -1), '"', 1) AS order_id FROM inventory_reservation ir3
) to_be_deleted WHERE to_be_deleted.order_id IN (
    SELECT entity_id FROM sales_order WHERE entity_id IN (
        SELECT msi_info.order_id FROM (
            SELECT ir1.*, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ir1.metadata, '_id":"', -1), '"', 1) AS order_id FROM inventory_reservation ir1
        ) msi_info WHERE msi_info.order_id IN (
            SELECT msi_info.order_id FROM (
                SELECT ir2.*, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ir2.metadata, '_id":"', -1), '"', 1) AS order_id FROM inventory_reservation ir2
            ) msi_info GROUP BY msi_info.order_id HAVING sum(msi_info.quantity)<>0
        )
    ) AND created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK 
);
```

You might be able to fix it by running this query.

```
DELETE FROM inventory_reservation WHERE reservation_id IN (
    SELECT to_be_deleted.reservation_id FROM (
        SELECT ir3.*, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ir3.metadata, '_id":"', -1), '"', 1) AS order_id FROM inventory_reservation ir3
    ) to_be_deleted WHERE to_be_deleted.order_id IN (
        SELECT entity_id FROM sales_order WHERE entity_id IN (
            SELECT msi_info.order_id FROM (
                SELECT ir1.*, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ir1.metadata, '_id":"', -1), '"', 1) AS order_id FROM inventory_reservation ir1
            ) msi_info WHERE msi_info.order_id IN (
                SELECT msi_info.order_id FROM (
                    SELECT ir2.*, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ir2.metadata, '_id":"', -1), '"', 1) AS order_id FROM inventory_reservation ir2
                ) msi_info GROUP BY msi_info.order_id HAVING sum(msi_info.quantity)<>0
            )
        ) AND created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND state IN ('closed', 'complete', 'canceled')
    )
);
```

Comment: this query  dont work properly because it take the last _id:" try to update with object_id:"

Comment: Hi @nino.aratari, to me it worked, what did you change to make it work for you?