# PHP Fatal error on inventory:reservation:list-inconsistencies command

Tags: magento2.4, inventory, msi, magento2.4.0, reservations

Magento 2.4.0
PHP 7.3
MariaDB 10.4

When I try to run this command: bin/magento inventory:reservation:list-inconsistencies -r

I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\InventoryReservationCli\Model\SalableQuantityInconsistency::setOrderStatus() must be of the type string, null given, called in /magento/vendor/magento/module-inventory-reservation-cli/Model/SalableQuantityInconsistency/Collector.php on line 129 and defined in /magento/vendor/magento/module-inventory-reservation-cli/Model/SalableQuantityInconsistency.php:166
Stack trace:
#0 /magento/vendor/magento/module-inventory-reservation-cli/Model/SalableQuantityInconsistency/Collector.php(129): Magento\InventoryReservationCli\Model\SalableQuantityInconsistency->setOrderStatus(NULL)
#1 /magento/vendor/magento/module-inventory-reservation-cli/Model/SalableQuantityInconsistency/AddExpectedReservations.php(86): Magento\InventoryReservationCli\Model\SalableQuantityInconsistency\Collector->addOrderData(Array)
```

I have a feeling that this could be because of some data formatting error in the db. [I tried running the query suggested in this thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/330654/56651) and I get a bunch of warnings

```
Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '11-1606368878'
Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '11-1606369154'
```

The order number format is what is used by the MageStore PWA POS module.

Any idea how I can fix this? There are a bunch of products that are visible as in stock on the website but can't be purchased.

Thanks!